# HTML YouTube iframe player is blurry, but video itself is fine

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I'm appending an iframe to the body of my html using jquery as a pop-up and styling it in CSS as a fixed element in the centre of the screen. Everything is okay and the video image itself has no quality issues, but the buttons and title in the iframe are strangely blurry.

[image: Here's the odd blur]

Here's the JS that brings it in:

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $("#filterHost").addClass("popFilter");
    $("body").append("<iframe class=\"popVideoPlay\" src=\"https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VEOJcZk8R5U/&vq=hd1080\"  allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
})
```

And here's the CSS that styles it

```
.popVideoPlay {
width: 70vw;
height: calc(70vw/1.66666);
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 10;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's a question of "resolution" I mean the width and its relation with the height of the iframe. delete the `height` or the `width` from the css

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip. That's what I thought it might be, but when I delete either one the iframe becomes either super thin or super flat. What's the best way of getting around that?

Comment: by using javascript maybe. Delete both height and width from the css first, then with javascript when the body load you get the height and width of the iframe and then multiply them by the same amount

Comment: That's fixed the blur - thank you! I do now have an issue with making the iframe responsive though. Any chance you have a quick fix there too?

Comment: listen to `window.onresize`